# Find nearest element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html:

```
<div class="row">
    <article>1</article>
    <article>2</article>
    <div class="load-work"></div>
    <article>3</article>
    <article>4</article>
    <div class="load-work"></div>
    <article>5</article>
    <article>6</article>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to find nearest `.load-work` to clicked `article`. My current JS is:

```
$('article').each(function() {          $(this).on('click', function() {
        $('.load-work').each(function() {
            $(this).hide().removeClass('loaded-work').html('');
        });
        $(this).closest('.row').find('.load-work').show().addClass('loaded-work')
    })
});
```

But it doesn't work - it finds each. Here's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naw8W/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this with `.nextAll()` and `:first`:

```
    $('article').on('click', function () {
         $('.load-work').each(function () {
               $(this).hide().removeClass('loaded-work').html('');
         });
         $(this).nextAll('.load-work:first').show().addClass('loaded-work');
    });
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naw8W/2/)

---

Or better one:

```
  $('article').on('click', function () {
       $('.load-work').each(function () {
           $(this).hide().removeClass('loaded-work').html('');
       });
       if($(this).nextAll('.load-work:first').length){
           $(this).nextAll('.load-work:first').show().addClass('loaded-work');
       }else{
           $(this).prevAll('.load-work:first').show().addClass('loaded-work');
       }
   });
```

#### [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naw8W/4/)

Comment: This is incorrect if you click on article `3`. The closest `.load-work` should be the one right before it but here the result will be the `.load-work` next to article `4`

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
$('article').each(function() {          $(this).on('click', function() {
        $('.load-work').each(function() {
            $(this).hide().removeClass('loaded-work').html('');
        });
        $(this).parent().closest('.row').find('.load-work').first().show().addClass('loaded-work')
    })
});
```

Working fiddle=> http://jsfiddle.net/naw8W/3/